# Angular 4 typed.js is not a constructor issue

Tags: javascript, constructor, components, angular-cli

I am trying to build my new portfolio with Angular 4 but came across few issues.
I first built it with normal html,css and js and worked fine.

I am using typed.js to create an animation at the beginning.
This are the steps that I followed:

1 - in node_modules created folder typed within typed.min.js

2 - angular-cli.json under scripts section "../node_modules/typed/typed.min.js"

3 - in typed component i imported as: import * as typed from 
'../../../../node_modules/typed/typed.min.js'; (apparently not working today and the terminal is saying this `ERROR in src/app/components/loading-section/loading-section.component.ts(2,24): error TS6143: Module '../../../../node_modules/typed/typed.min.js' was resolved to '/Users/matteosoresini/Development/Portfolio2017/node_modules/typed/typed.min.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.` so if i change the path as the terminal says is working but doesn't really make sense but this is not the main issue.

4 - in ngInit i tried to implement the JS function and when run the project the terminal says typed is not a constructor, even if i move the function inside a script within the typed.component.html

can you please help me with this and clarify where to import external plugin?
Thanks

[image: typed.component.html]

[image: typed.component.ts]

[image: angular-cli.json]

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: no not really unfortunately !!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to install typed.js via `npm install typed.js --save`.

I then tried to use `import { Typed } from 'typed.js';` as shown in the typed.js documentation. That threw the not a constructor error.

I changed the import to `import * as Typed from 'typed.js';` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Types.js has no defined typescript types in DefinitelyTyped repo. 
I not sure how it would behave with Angular since it does DOM changes outside angular. You can see and try https://github.com/kuflink/angular-typed but it is not production ready.